# How can I write a The Breadth First Search algorithm on a linked data structure?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, linked-list

We can use a queue and mark all the nodes to do BFS. This is easy if the graph is stored in adjacency matrix, where we can easily get how many nodes are there and create an marker array.

What should I do if I have such TreeNode definition? (Giving such definition, I do not know how many nodes are in the tree.)

```
# Definition for a  binary tree node
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Comment: What  have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I am new to algorithms. At the first step, I need to allocate a marker for each node. I do not know how to assign such a marker array. @schwobaseggl

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding information in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a start position and a queue to store the nodes, along with a set to store all marked nodes:

```
from collections import deque
class TreeNode:
   def __init__(self, x):
      self.val = x
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.children = [self.left, self.right] #for easier transversing

root_node = TreeNode(1)
... #node declarations follow below
d = deque([root_node])
target = 5
flag = False
marked = {root_node.val}
while d:
   current_node = d.popleft()
   marked.add(current_node.val)
   d.extend([i for i in current_node.children if i and i.val not in marked])
   if current_node == target:
      flag = True
      break

print('found' if flag else "not found")
```

This code above follows the generic steps for breadth first search:

1. Add root node to queue and mark as visited.
2. while the queue is not empty do:

   1. pop the first element from the queue and check if it is equal to the target value. If so, break. Else, go to 2.
   2. extend the queue with all the child nodes of first element, popped from the queue in 1, that have not been marked.
   3. Mark the first element as transversed.

Comment: @hxd1011 yes, that is actually more efficient. I will edit my post.

Comment: thanks for answer this basic question. I am preparing for an interview, but what I learned in school is using adjacency matrix.

Comment: @hxd1011 glad to help! I added an additional explanation of this code in my post.